# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Autocorrelation - Stochastic vs deterministic processes](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11316/autocorrelation-stochastic-vs-deterministic-processes)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Entropy Of A Symbol](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/entropy-of-a-symbol)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [QPSK, from Square Root Raised Cosine to Rectangular Impulse Shaping](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/qpsk-from-square-root-raised-cosine-to-rectangular-impulse-shaping)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Applying Kalman filter to a data set](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11374/applying-kalman-filter-to-a-data-set)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is PSD estimated, and not simply computed?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/why-is-psd-estimated-and-not-simply-computed)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [strange phenomenon in spectrogram of Windowed Fourier Transform [edited]](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/strange-phenomenon-in-spectrogram-of-windowed-fourier-transform-edited)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why sinc function defined on minus side?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11547/why-sinc-function-defined-on-minus-side)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Haar series approximation of a function?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/haar-series-approximation-of-a-function)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [why if we pad any signal with enough zeros we can get the same result](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/why-if-we-pad-any-signal-with-enough-zeros-we-can-get-the-same-result)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Getting an specific frequency component from sampled audio](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/getting-an-specific-frequency-component-from-sampled-audio)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---